# Solving $2\cos\theta −1=0$ for $0^\circ\le \theta\le 720^\circ$. How to handle the $720^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry

The question asks to solve the equation

> $$2\cos\theta −1=0$$

for $0^\circ\le \theta\le 720^\circ$, but I have never worked with $720^\circ$, only $360^\circ$. So, how can I solve it?

Comment: If $x^\circ$ is a solution, so is $(x+360)^\circ$ since that's essentially the same angle.

Comment: Ok I was able to solve it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let us begin by isolating the variable $\theta$.
$$2\cos(\theta)-1=0\implies\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\implies\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Now, we need to find the angles in the given interval whose cosine is $1/2$. We know that the cosine function is positive in the first and fourth quadrants, so $\pi/3$ and $5\pi/3$ will be solutions to the equation in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Following user Angina Seng's logic in the comments, we can add $2\pi$ to these solutions in order to find the solutions in the interval $[2\pi,4\pi]$. This is because $\cos(\theta+2\pi)=\cos(\theta)$. This gives us $7\pi/3$ and $11\pi/3$, respectively. Thus, we now have all of our solutions in $[0,4\pi]$ and have finished solving the problem.
$$\theta=\left\{\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{5\pi}{3},\frac{7\pi}{3},\frac{11\pi}{3}\right\}$$